# MySQL Workbench Create SQL Statements error when implementing in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, workbench

I Created a Whole Database in MySQL Workbench and now im trying to import it to my DB on my Webhost through phpMyAdmin. The Workbench created following code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_web375_4`.`Sandwich` (
  `Sandwich_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Style_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Bread_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Cheese_ID` INT NULL,
  `Size_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sandwich_Toasted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `Sandwich_Prize` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sandwich_ID`),
  INDEX `Style_ID_idx` (`Style_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Bread_ID_idx` (`Bread_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Cheese_ID_idx` (`Cheese_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Size_ID_idx` (`Size_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Style_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Style_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Style` (`Style_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Bread_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Bread_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Bread` (`Bread_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Cheese_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Cheese_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Cheese` (`Cheese_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Size_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Size_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Size` (`Size_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_web375_4`.`Sauce` (
  `Sauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sauce_Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Sauce_IMG` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Sauce_Nutrition` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sauce_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `usr_web375_4`.`SandwichSauce`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_web375_4`.`SandwichSauce` (
  `SandwichSauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sandwich_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SandwichSauce_ID`),
  INDEX `Sandwich_ID_idx` (`Sandwich_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Sauce_ID_idx` (`Sauce_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Sandwich_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sandwich_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Sandwich` (`Sandwich_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Sauce_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sauce_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Sauce` (`Sauce_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

i tried it either with the import function and the code section.
It gives me following error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_web375_4`.`SandwichSauce` (
```

`SandwichSauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sandwich_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SandwichSauce_ID`),
  INDEX `Sandwich_ID_idx` (`Sandwich_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Sauce_ID_idx` (`Sauce_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Sandwich_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sandwich_ID`)

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'usr_web375_4.SandwichSauce' (errno: 121) (Details…)
```

I don't get it. there was no error in workbench

I'm not sure if it has maybe something to do with this table i successfully created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_web375_4`.`SandwichVegtable` (
  `SandwichVegtable_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sandwich_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Vegtable_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SandwichVegtable_ID`),
  INDEX `Sandwich_ID_idx` (`Sandwich_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Vegtable_ID_idx` (`Vegtable_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Sandwich_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sandwich_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Sandwich` (`Sandwich_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Vegtable_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Vegtable_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Vegtable` (`Vegtable_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a type for Sandwich_ID and  Sauce_ID in your `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`usr_web375_4.SandwichSauce ...

and you must use a unique names for all your indexes and constraints.

Could you try this code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_web375_4`.`SandwichSauce` (
  `SandwichSauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sandwich_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Sauce_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SandwichSauce_ID`),
  INDEX `Sandwich_ID_idx` (`Sandwich_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Sauce_ID_idx` (`Sauce_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Sandwich_ID_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sandwich_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Sandwich` (`Sandwich_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Sauce_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sauce_ID`)
    REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Sauce` (`Sauce_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Or in workbench you can run this query and export the DB again :

```
 ALTER TABLE `SandwichSauce` DROP FOREIGN KEY `Sandwich_ID`;
 ALTER TABLE `SandwichSauce` ADD CONSTRAINT `Sandwich_ID_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Sandwich_ID`) REFERENCES `usr_web375_4`.`Sandwich`(`Sandwich_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I updated the error message in my questionpost as well ;) and i now add another table i created, because i think it could have something to do with it.

Comment: I think the problem is the name of your index Sandwich_ID_idx, you already used  this name in your SandwichVegtable table , so try to change it

Comment: If i completly leave it out or if i change the index name there is still the same error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127035/discussion-between-imanez-and-j-doe).